# Copy element from one array and move the value to another

Tags: java, arrays

I want my program to "sort" an array into two different arrays. Meaning every value that is greater than or equal to 500 goes to the array values2. Every value that is less than 500 goes to the array values3.

My problem is that whatever I try its always the last value that matches the condition that is shown.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length && i < noOfNumbers; i++)
        {

            if (values[i] >= 500)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < numbersAbove500; k++)
                {

                    values3[k] = values[i];
                }
            }
                    else 
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < numbersAbove500; j++)
                        {
                        values2[j] = values[i];

                        }
                    }



        }
```

Typical Output

How many numbers do you wish the array to contain? 8

**These are the random numbers**

877 338 741 119 20 853 235 786

**These are the numbers above or equal to 500 :**

786 786 786 786

**These are the numbers below 500 :**

235 235 235 235

Comment: is numbersAbove500 your counter of numbers that are larger than 500?

Comment: Why to think hard? Why not to sort just one array, and then split it to two different arrays? ;)

Comment: yeah luk2302 i use it to see the total numbers above 500

Comment: Alex, I'm not allowed to use the sort function in this assignment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a single loop. Your inner loops make no sense.

```
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length && i < noOfNumbers; i++) {
    if (values[i] >= 500) {
        values3[k] = values[i];
        k++;
    } else {
        values2[j] = values[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```